# How to force Quartz to run sequentially in cluster mode

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz with Spring Boot for one of services, and despite having clustered configuration and usage of @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation I observe that job is triggered multiple times.

Funny thing is, that this happens only after the restart of the service. After couple of runs job "sets itself"into correct execution mode.

My config

```
spring:
  quartz:
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore:
        class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
        driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
        isClustered: true
        clusterCheckinInterval: 500
        acquireTriggersWithinLock: true
        tablePrefix: qtz_
      org.quartz.scheduler:
        instanceName: CompanyProfileScheduler
        instanceId: AUTO
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
```

My job conig

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobDetail companyProfilePublishingSchedulerJobDetails() {
        return JobBuilder
                .newJob(CompanyProfilePublishingJob.class)
                .withIdentity("CompanyProfilePublishingScheduler")
                .storeDurably()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Trigger companyProfilePublishingTrigger(final JobDetail companyProfilePublishingSchedulerJobDetails) {
        return TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .forJob(companyProfilePublishingSchedulerJobDetails)
                .withIdentity("CompanyProfilePublishingSchedulerTrigger")
                .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder
                                .simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInSeconds(CompanyProfilePublishingJob.RUN_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS)
                                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount()
                                .repeatForever())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Job

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class CompanyProfilePublishingJob extends QuartzJobBean {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show and your database connection properties. Have you created jobDetail after adding annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution? Because only this annotation existence control one job instance in a time.